# Clear Input Field on Invalid Input Entered in Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am Using [devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)

**What am I Doing?**

I have Appended This Autocomplete to the Input Field.
As Autocomplete Behaviour It's Allow You to type and Show Some Suggestion according to the Lookup data.

So, User can simply type some letter and they get suggested data according to it.

When User Select anything from that suggested data I save its id for further operations. I save that id in hidden input field.

It Works Fine.

**The Problem:**

> Case 1: 1st Time When user select anything from the list and it's id
>   get to the hidden input. That's Work Ok.
>
> But When User Decided To Change it and the New value is not in the
>   list then Obyesly I have to clear the hidden input Which I am not Able
>   to clear.(this is the problem1)
>
> Case 2: Autocomplete has the option - **onInvalidateSelection** But
>   it's not working for me.

This is the Code:

```
$('body').on('focus',".qualification_major_data", function(){

  var qualifications_major_string = [{data: "1", value: "Tom Smith"},
                        {data: "2", value: "Tommy Smith"},
                        {data: "3", value: "add Smith"}];

 $(this).autocomplete({

                lookup: qualifications_major_string,
                appendTo: '.qualification_major_div',
                minChars: 2,
                onSelect: function (suggestion) {

                // On select I am Saving the Id of the Selected Value to the Hidden Input
                     alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
                    var selectedValueID = suggestion.data;
                    $(this).closest('.qualification_major_div').find('input[name="qualification_major_id_hidden[]"]').val(selectedValueID);
                },                
                onInvalidateSelection: function() { 

                    // On Invalid Select or Enter I want to Clear the Hidden Input Value. Which I am not Able to do.
                    // This Part is the Problem
                    $('.qualification_major_div input[name="qualification_major_id_hidden[]"]').val('');
                },
                showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
                noSuggestionNotice: 'Sorry, no matching results'

            });

});
```

This is the HTML Part of It:

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group qualification_major_div">
          <label for="qualification_major" class="control-label">Qualification Major *</label>
          <input type="text" name="qualification_major_id[]" id="qualification_major_id" required class="form-control require qualification_major_data" />
          <input type="hidden" id="qualification_major_id_hidden" name="qualification_major_id_hidden[]">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Tkirda Can You Help Me over this sir?

Comment: So should the user be able to type his own data or only select something from autocomplete?

Comment: Yes, the user is free to add their own data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am Posting Answer myself because this is what works for me not the Proper solution but it just a workaround for this problem.

First I had to change the event to **keypress** from  **focus**. Then I notice that in the dynamically created field if we want to do something with particular element then we need something unique id or class related to that element. So I add a unique class dynamically only for the particular event.(after event I remove that added class).

And For Autocomplete Problem to get the changed value id I have used it's one of attribute  **noSuggestionNotice** because it's trigger every time when I change the value.

> 1 Step: I have decided to use **noSuggestionNotice** for removing id.

```
noSuggestionNotice: function (suggestion) {
    $('.currentQualificationMajor').closest('.qualification_major_div').find('input[name="qualification_major_id_hidden[]"]').val('');
}
```

> 2 Step: I have to change the event to **keypress**

```
 $('#qualification_outer_div').on('keypress', '.qualification_major_data', function(){
```

> 3 Step: Since I am adding this autocomplete dynamically, so I have to
>   take a Unique Class or id to do something with a particular input. So
>   I add this script of added the class to the field wich is currently on
>   keypress.

```
$(this).addClass("currentQualificationMajor");
```

> 4 Step: So after script over I am removing the class which I added.

```
$(this).removeClass("currentQualificationMajor");
```

Here is the Complete code:

```
$('#qualification_outer_div').on('keypress', '.qualification_major_data', function(){

$(this).addClass("currentQualificationMajor"); 

$('.currentQualificationMajor').autocomplete({

        lookup: qualifications_major_string,
        appendTo: '.qualification_major_div',
        minChars: 2,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {

            var selectedValueID = suggestion.data;
            $(this).closest('.qualification_major_div').find('input[name="qualification_major_id_hidden[]"]').val(selectedValueID);
        },                
        onInvalidateSelection: function() {                                 
            $(this).closest('.qualification_major_div').find('input[name="qualification_major_id_hidden[]"]').val('');
        },
        showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
        noSuggestionNotice: function (suggestion) {

              $('.currentQualificationMajor').closest('.qualification_major_div').find('input[name="qualification_major_id_hidden[]"]').val('');
        }

    });
});
```

I am not giving this answer a correct because it's just a workaround, not the proper solution. But it's work.

Comment: have you ever tried change event for this. I mean just track that input value change and remove id from hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and it works good. The only thing I have changed is `$('body').on('focus',".qualification_major_data", function(){`

I don't find it useful that you instantiate all array of objects every time you click on the input field. If there's a reason behind it, feel free to leave it like that. If not, then delete that function and replace  `$(this).autocomplete({`

with
 `$('#qualification_major_id').autocomplete({`

What's causing your errors (Case1 and Case2)? I know it may sound strange, but it's the actual `alert()` I would suggest you to use `console.log()` in future.

I've made you a JSFiddle and left some comments also.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngcrxLnj/6/)

Comment: Thanks, I will keep it in mind for future. (console log).  Actually, I am using this auto complete in a different way.  User Can Dynamically Add more of this input so I use a class instead of id.  I will Explain it to you that This is the Qualification Filed so a user can add more qualification as he wishes so I used a class instead of id for it.  Hope You understand.

Comment: Feel free to customize it as it fits you the best. It's hard to know only from the code you provided. And yes, console.log is a way to go. You won't be able to inspect the arrays and objects in depth with alert

Comment: What's causing your errors (Case1 and Case2)?  -- Both the Case. I show the fiddle and it's almost it what I need.

Comment: Great, I'm glad if I helped.

Comment: This Autocomplete is on the bootstrap model & also in an external Js file. Is it the problem? because it's not working? when I remove that 'focus' code and put the class instead of this.

Comment: You want to use only one class when attaching  the autocomplete.   $('.form-control').autocomplete({     or       $('.qualification_major_data').autocomplete({

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146039/discussion-between-ankit-suthar-and-masterfan).